# Why do files with longer names have a smaller hitbox on the desktop?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I was waiting for something, and I started doing random stuff with the selector box on the desktop, and I noticed, that some files in the same row get selected sometimes, but some not. I tried a few times, and I noticed, that the files I selected first had a shorter name. In fact, if a file has a 3 row name, it gets selected after the 2 row ones.

A gif to make it clearer

[image]

Also, I'm not quite sure if this goes here or not, so please correct me if I'm at the wrong place.

Comment: That's a very interesting question.

Comment: At a guess, the selection hitbox is a fixed size significantly smaller than the highlight box size (probably just the icon size) and is ***centered* on the icon + text highlight box**. That both explains why *all* icons don't get selected until you've dragged part way over their icons (even single-line names meant the hitbox gets moved down a few pixels) and explains why names with more lines have lower hitboxes. It you try selecting the files from the bottom up, I bet they get selected slightly *before* you hit the icon (and further for long names), but not at the bottom of the text.

Comment: @CBHacking Yeah, files with longer names get selected first when tried from below, but that's what I thought would happen

Comment: @CBHacking Also, it's definitely not fixed size, the difference between the hitboxes at the top is just a couple pixels, while at the bottom, it's 10-20 px depending on the row count

Comment: Looks like (center of mass). A compensation routine built into the OS. It's reverse is true from bottom, up.

Comment: @ejbytes Again, the difference at the top is just 1-2 pixels, while at the bottom it's 10-20

Comment: Not really. If you make the filename 10 lines high, then it's quite, quite, a bit more than 2 pixels. It ends up being about 15 to 16.

Comment: @ejbytes I meant 2 pixel per line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, Windows selects icons if you include a certain share of them in the selection box. Icons with longer titles are higher, as they extend down because of the linebreaks in their title. You therefore need to select more of them to hit the treshold.

As for why this was implemented I can only guess that it is the same algorithm that governs all icon selection, and is a useful approach that works for all icon sizes (try [Ctrl]+Mouse Wheel to resize icons and preview images).

Answer (score -1):

Possible work-around.  Why not try making one hit box using the longest name then replicating that box and changing the name and formula?  When you change the name, if the box wants to get smaller try adding spaces to fill in before or after the name. You might consider adding characters and changing their font color to the background color if the spaces don't work.  Also change the font of your text, chosing one whose characters are all the same width.

Comment: I'm asking why it happens, not how to fix it